# How to take backup of logs generated by Amazon ec2 instance during runtime

Tags: hadoop, amazon-ec2, virtual-machine, hive

I have cron-jobs which will create hive instances using elastic-mapreduce to run my queries to process raw-data from amazon s3 folder and push the data to the database. 
After the cron-job runs, it will create an amazon ec2 instance in amazon vm. If there are any errors in the job the logs are stored in the vm and will vanish once the ec2 instance is shut down. Is there any way to send those logs to email or to any other server where I can investigate the logs even after the vm is shut down,.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at log rotate, it can zip your log files periodically and you can choose which log file u want to rotate and also you can send the zip file to a desired email also. http://geekospace.com/using-logrotate-to-rotate-log-files/ (Disclaimer: I wrote this ariticle)